# Loop iterations overwrite previous values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

One of tasks produces the following list of dictionaries:

```json
"ne_hosts": [
        {
            "instance_class": "docker_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.15"
        },
        {
            "instance_class": "vm_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.13"
        }
    ]
```

I'd like to update each dictionary with additional key-value pair to become:

```json
"ne_hosts_updated": [
        {
            "instance_class": "docker_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.15",
            "ip_present": 1
        },
        {
            "instance_class": "vm_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.13",
            "ip_present": 0
        }
    ]
```

The following two tasks get launched to a) check condition and generate helper variable and b) update the initial list with key-value pairs according to met conditions (if an IP was found in config file, the return code is 0, otherwise it's 1):

```yaml
    - name: Check if host IP is present in a config file
      ansible.builtin.command: grep -q "{{ target_config_file_location }}" -e "{{ item.ip }}"
      loop: "{{ ne_hosts }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: ip_present

    - name: Update the IPs list
      set_fact:
        ne_hosts_updated: "{{ ne_hosts | default([]) | map('combine', {'ip_present': item.rc }) | list }}"
      loop: "{{ ip_present.results }}"
```

After these tasks are complete, additional key-value pair gets added to each dictionary. However, the values of `ip_present` key always correspond to the last checked IP, so either:

```json
"ne_hosts_updated": [
        {
            "instance_class": "docker_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.15",
            "ip_present": 1
        },
        {
            "instance_class": "vm_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.13",
            "ip_present": 1
        }
    ]
```

or:

```json
"ne_hosts_updated": [
        {
            "instance_class": "docker_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.15",
            "ip_present": 0
        },
        {
            "instance_class": "vm_host",
            "ip": "10.11.12.13",
            "ip_present": 0
        }
    ]
```

How to make sure the loop iterations don't overwrite previous values and generate values corresponding to currently checked IP value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the file, for example,

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/target.conf 
10.11.12.11
10.11.12.12
10.11.12.13
```

---

To answer your question:

Q: ***"How to make sure the loop iterations don't overwrite previous values?"***

A: Add the items of the updated list in the loop. The play below

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ne_hosts:
      - {ip: 10.11.12.15, instance_class: docker_host}
      - {ip: 10.11.12.13, instance_class: vm_host}

    target_config_file_location: /tmp/target.conf

  tasks:

    - command: "grep -q {{ target_config_file_location }} -e {{ item.ip }}"
      loop: "{{ ne_hosts }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: ip_present

    - set_fact:
        ne_hosts_updated: "{{ ne_hosts_updated|default([]) +
                              [ne_hosts[ansible_loop.index0]|
                               combine({'ip_present': item.rc })] }}"
      loop: "{{ ip_present.results }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
    - debug:
        var: ne_hosts_updated|to_yaml
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  ne_hosts_updated:
    - {instance_class: docker_host, ip: 10.11.12.15, ip_present: 1}
    - {instance_class: vm_host, ip: 10.11.12.13, ip_present: 0}
```

See: [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)

---

However, it's simpler to read the content into a variable. (There are also other options/modules *fetch*, *slurp* ... Let's keep the module *command* here for simplicity).

```yaml
    - command: "cat {{ target_config_file_location }}"
      register: target_conf
```

gives

```yaml
  target_conf.stdout:
    10.11.12.11
    10.11.12.12
    10.11.12.13
```

Then, use it in Jinja

```yaml
  ne_hosts_updated: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in ne_hosts %}
    {% if i.ip in target_conf.stdout %}
    - {{ i|combine({'ip_present': 0}) }}
    {% else %}
    - {{ i|combine({'ip_present': 1}) }}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  ne_hosts_updated:
    - {instance_class: docker_host, ip: 10.11.12.15, ip_present: 1}
    - {instance_class: vm_host, ip: 10.11.12.13, ip_present: 0}
```

---

Optionally, create a list of the *ip_present* hashes

```yaml
  ip_present_query: '[].{"ip_present": contains(`{{ target_conf.stdout_lines }}`, ip)}'
  ip_present: "{{ ne_hosts|json_query(ip_present_query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ip_present:
  - ip_present: false
  - ip_present: true
```

and combine them

```yaml
  ne_hosts_update: "{{ ne_hosts|zip(ip_present)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ne_hosts_update:
    - {instance_class: docker_host, ip: 10.11.12.15, ip_present: false}
    - {instance_class: vm_host, ip: 10.11.12.13, ip_present: true}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ne_hosts:
      - {ip: 10.11.12.15, instance_class: docker_host}
      - {ip: 10.11.12.13, instance_class: vm_host}

    target_config_file_location: /tmp/target.conf
    ne_hosts_updated: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in ne_hosts %}
      {% if i.ip in target_conf.stdout %}
      - {{ i|combine({"ip_present": 0}) }}
      {% else %}
      - {{ i|combine({'ip_present': 1}) }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    ip_present_query: '[].{"ip_present": contains(`{{ target_conf.stdout_lines }}`, ip)}'
    ip_present: "{{ ne_hosts|json_query(ip_present_query) }}"
    ne_hosts_update2: "{{ ne_hosts|zip(ip_present)|map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: "cat {{ target_config_file_location }}"
      register: target_conf
    - debug:
        var: target_conf

    - debug:
        var: ne_hosts_updated|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: ip_present
    - debug:
        var: ne_hosts_update2|to_yaml
```